# MVC persist route data value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

How can i work with MVC so once a user is logged into the site it follows the URL pattern

```
pattern: "{username}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

I have added the following end point in Startup.cs Configure()

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "username",
                pattern: "{username}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

This is working fine if i manually type in the URL the pages load as expected.
But as soon as navigate around the site using the route value is lost and it defaults back to

```
pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

How can i persist the url route 'username' value?

Using .Net 5 and Tag Helpers.

Comment: "But as soon as navigate around the site using the route value is lost",what does this mean?When you route without username,it will go to default route?

Comment: @YiyiYou if for example i manually navigate to /{myusername}/account/myprofile which will work and i have a link on that page to edit my account .e.g <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Edit">Edit </a> instead of navigating to /{myusername}/account/edit it will just navigate to /account/edit.
So i was wondering how i can persist the /{username}/ route value.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are also in the Account Controller,you can try to use:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="Edit">Edit </a>
```

result:
[image]

Or you can use js to get the current url,then get username from it  and add it into a link href.Here is a demo to change all the  links href:
html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Edit" >Edit </a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Create">Create </a>
```

js:

```
 $(function () {
        var s = window.location.href.split("/")[3];
        $("a").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("href", "/" + s + $(this).attr("href"))
        })
        
    })
```

result:
[image]